# Is there a way to determine if a keyup elem -is not- a particular parent or that parents children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to find a solution for this after hours of searching :-(

I've tried to no avail:

```
jQuery('#someGlobalNav').delegate('*','keyup', function(){
   if(!(jQuery('#itemsForSale').find(jQuery(this))){// do something}

jQuery("#itemsForSale, #itemsForSale > * ").focusout(function(){}
```

Tried using :not, and :contains.

Basically, I have a grouping of links. Lets use this below:

```
<div id="someGlobalNav">
<ul id='siteNavigation'>
<li id="itemsForSale">
   <div id="items">
      <ul id='itemNav'>
         <li>
             <div id="menu1">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="link">menu 1 item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="link">menu 1 item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </li>
         <li>
              <div id="menu2">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="link">menu 2 item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="link">menu 2 item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</li>
<li><a href="link">Link that Might exist</a></li>
<li><a href="link">AnotherLink that Might exist</a></li>
</ul>
<div><a href="somelink">Arbitrary link</a></div>
</div>
```

everything is captured fine etc.. the only issue is, I want to ONLY act on elems that are NOT "itemsForSale" or its children. So, as a user keyups thru links, all is fine UNTIL they keyup on somethign outside of itemsForSale --

I figured to use :not - but I won't know the selectors as the nav is dynamic. I tried all sorts of other things no luck.

Any ideas

Comment: [*As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Yeah - I am using jQuery 1.6 and don't have the option to upgrade. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An over simplified solution to your problem would be like this:

```
$('a:not(#itemsForSale *)');
```

Demo on jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/idijos/1/edit

Comment: I think I can modify what you have to make it work. I will like it, and after I am done testing, I'll accept. I appreciate your reply, thank you.